# Convert pointfree to pointful

Tags: code-golf, string, function

Being a Haskell hacker, I prefer pointfree notation over pointful. Unfortunately some people find pointfree notation hard to read, and I find it hard to get the correct number of parentheses when I write in pointful.
Help me convert code written in pointfree to pointful notation!

### About

In pointfree notation we use points (yes, really) to feed the output of one function into another. Say, if you had a function `succ` that takes a number and adds 1 to it, and you wanted to make a function that adds 3 to a number, instead of doing this:

```
\x -> succ(succ(succ(x)))
```

you could do this:

```
succ.succ.succ
```

Pointfree only works with functions that take a single parameter however (in this challenge anyway), so if our function wasn't `succ` but rather `add` which take 2 numbers and adds them together, we would have to feed it arguments until there is only one left:

```
pointful:  \x -> add 1(add 1(add 1 x)) 
pointfree: add 1 . add 1 . add 1
```

Lastly, functions may take other functions as arguments:

```
Pointfree: map (f a . f b) . id
Pointful:  \x -> map (\x -> f a (f b x)) (id x)

Javascript equivalent: x => map (x => f(a,f(b,x)), id(x))
```

### Input and expected output

```
f . f . f
\x -> f (f (f x))

f a . f b . f c
\x -> f a (f b (f c x))

f (f a . f b) . f c
\x -> f (\x -> f a (f b x)) (f c x)

a b c . d e . f g h i . j k l . m
\x -> a b c (d e (f g h i (j k l (m x))))

a.b(c.d)e.f g(h)(i j.k).l(m(n.o).p)
\x->a(b(\y->c(d y))e(f g h(\z->i j(k z))(l(\q->m(\w->n(o w))(p q))x)))
```

### Rules

- Your output may have more spaces or parentheses than required, as long as they are balanced
- You don't have to make sure that the name of the variable you create `\x` isn't already used somewhere else in the code
- It is your choice whether to create a function or a full program
- This is `codegolf`, shortest code in bytes win!

You might find blunt useful, it converts between the two notations (but also factorizes the code when possible): https://blunt.herokuapp.com

Comment: _In pointfree notation we use points to feed the output of one function into another_ That's clearly an attempt to prove that pointfree is not pointless

Comment: "Pointfree only works with functions that take a single parameter". That's not true: `(+).(*3)` is the same as `\x y->3*x+y`

Comment: @Damien I was trying to make the challenge more accessible. You can also do things like the owl: `(.).(.)` which converts to `\i b c f -> i (b c f)`

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the clarification. As a huge fan of pointfree style, I had to notice that.

Comment: So for clarity for those who don't know the syntax of Haskell by heart: we should first match parentheses in the input and recurse on each top-level parenthesised expression; and then replace each `.` with a `(`, prepend a `\x` and append a corresponding `x` and as many `)` as are required? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, that's it exactly

Comment: This could be an interesting challenge for Dyalog APL or J too, but they have complex rules: `f g h` ≡ `{(f ⍵) g (h ⍵)}`, and allow two arguments, : `f g h` ≡ `{(⍺ f ⍵) g (⍺ h ⍵)}`...

Comment: Is it ok if an input like `(h)` will be converted to `(\x->h x)`? In my understanding `(h)` could be considered as pointfree, whereas `(\x->h x)` is definitely pointful.

Comment: I don't know Haskell but why doesn't [`f.(f.).f`](https://blunt.herokuapp.com/#input=f.(f.).f) resolve to `\d->f(\k->f(k))(f d)`?

Comment: @Linus `\ d->f(\k->f(f d k))`, but you can assume that all the dots are fed two arguments in this challenge

Comment: @Linus Oh, and it's because `(.) = \f a x -> f(a(x))`, so `(succ.) = \a x -> succ(a(x))` and `succ.succ = \x -> succ(succ(x))`

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>163 142</s> 133 bytes

```haskell
p(x:r)|[a,b]<-p r=case[x]of"("->["(\\x->"++a++p b!!0,""];"."->['(':a++")",b];")"->[" x)",r];_->[x:a,b]
p r=[r,r]
f s=p('(':s++")")!!0
```

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/tbgKLY)

Ungolfed:

```haskell
p('(':r)|(a,b)<-p r = ("(\\x->"++a++(fst(p b)),"")
p('.':r)|(a,b)<-p r = ('(':a++")",              b)
p(')':r)            = (" x)",                   r)
p(x  :r)|(a,b)<-p r = (x:a,                     b)
p _                 = ("",                     "")

f s=fst(p('(':s++")"))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>402</s> 289 bytes

Quite long, but I think it works..

```haskell
(!)=elem
n%'('=n+1
n%')'=n-1
n%_=n
a?n=a!"."&&n<1
a#n=a!" ("&&n<1||a!")"&&n<2
q a='(':a++")"
p s o n[]=[s]
p s o n(a:b)|o a n=[t|t@(q:r)<-s:p""o(n%a)b]|0<1=p(s++[a])o(n%a)b
k=foldr((++).(++" ").f)"".p""(#)0
f t|not$any(!"(. ")t=t|l@(x:r)<-p""(?)0t=q$"\\x->"++foldr((.q).(++).k)"x"l|0<1=k t
```